# Consulta SQL en Laravel, no me retorna ningun registro

Tags: sql, laravel, join, querybuilder

Necesito hacer una consulta SQL en donde todos los registros relacionados que coincidan con la validacion del where solamente se tomen en cuenta.

Este es mi script

```
USE pi;
select * from `table_candidats` 
inner join `users` on `table_candidats`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
inner join `levels` on `table_candidats`.`level_id` = `levels`.`id` 
inner join `languages` on `table_candidats`.`language_id` = `languages`.`id` 
inner join `table_class_times` on `table_candidats`.`class_time_id` = `table_class_times`.`id` 
inner join `table_careers` on `table_candidats`.`career_id` = `table_careers`.`id` 
inner join `period` 
on `table_candidats`.`id_period` = `period`.`id` WHERE `start-date` like `%Junio` and `end-date` like `%Marzo` and `year` = `2022`;
```

Pero no me esta devolviendo ningun registro ni error.

```
    $preinscriptions = DB::table('table_candidats')
    ->join('users', 'table_candidats.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('levels', 'table_candidats.level_id', '=', 'levels.id')
    ->join('languages', 'table_candidats.language_id', '=', 'languages.id')
    ->join('table_class_times', 'table_candidats.class_time_id', '=', 'table_class_times.id')
    ->join('table_careers', 'table_candidats.career_id', '=', 'table_careers.id')
    ->join('period', function($join) use ($startM,$endM,$request){

        $join->on('table_candidats.id_period', '=', 'period.id')
        ->where('start-date','like', "%$startM")
        ->where('end-date','like', "%$endM")
        ->where('year','=',$request->get('year'));

    })->get();
```

Al utilizarlo en Laravel no me retorna ningun registro.

Comment: No le especificas que devolver db::table("table").select("*"). Resto de codigo

Comment: No amigo, ya había realizado esa prueba

Comment: Me llama la atención que estés buscando `start-date` en lo que sea = `Junio` y que `end-date` lo que sea = `Marzo`.  Pero del año 2022. La fecha de inicio es mayor que la fecha de final para el mismo año???. Es raro. Por otro lado, si no hay un conjunto de datos donde poder probar, será dificil ayudarte. Primero sin el where te trae datos ? Si es así, luego, porque no vas quitando predicados del where y los vas añadiendo paulatinamente para ver que predicado hace que se escapen los datos.

Comment: Una opción muy interesante cuando se plantean este tipo de problemas, es, quitar el where y añadir varias columnas con un case when. En la columna vas poniendo los predicados que tenías en el where y ves que filas son las que si van cumpliendo y que filas no. Por ejemplo una columna para el primer predicado, una para el segundo y una para el tercero. Una para el primero y el segundo, ..... en esa linea visualmente, es probable que veas el error que tienes.

Comment: Lo de las fechas es por pruebas, al momento de haber realizado el registro lo hice de una manera rápida xd.
Respecto al tip muchas gracias lo tomare en cuenta en mis pruebas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedó solucionado, lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
    $preinscriptions = DB::table('table_candidats')
    ->select('*')
    ->join('users', 'table_candidats.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('table_levels', 'table_candidats.level_id', '=', 'table_levels.id')
    ->leftJoin('languages', 'table_candidats.language_id', '=', 'languages.id')
    ->leftJoin('table_class_times', 'table_candidats.class_time_id', '=', 'table_class_times.id')
    ->leftJoin('table_careers', 'table_candidats.career_id', '=', 'table_careers.id')
    ->join('period', 'table_candidats.id_period', 'period.id')
    ->where('year', '=', $request->get('year'))
    ->where(function ($query) use ($startM,$endM) {
        $query->where('start-date','like', "%$startM")
              ->where('end-date','like', "%$endM");
    })
    ->get();
```

Salu2.